# getDescribe() of an External Object throws NPE

Tags: apex, describesobject, schema, describefieldresult

I have a external object called "TD_Account__x" whose label is "TD Account". I am trying to do a describe call on "TD_Account__x" and it throws me NPE.

Execute anonymous code -

```
System.debug('@@ ==> ' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('TD_Account__x'));
System.debug('@@ ==> ' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('TD_Account__x').getDescribe());
```

Output -

```
31.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG

Execute Anonymous: System.debug('@@ ==> ' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('TD_Account__x'));    
Execute Anonymous: System.debug('@@ ==> ' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('TD_Account__x').getDescribe());    
22:21:48.021 (21681254)|EXECUTION_STARTED    
22:21:48.021 (21689686)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex    
22:21:48.061 (61430021)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|@@ ==> null    
22:21:48.063 (63610311)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object    
AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1
22:21:48.063 (63651629)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
22:21:48.064 (64901774)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Is there any way to get the schema information of external objects?